# How to access an Azure Blob that starts with a '/'?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob that is (according to Azure) at a URL of: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events//BAs1nRTx/00001f240_2020-05-12_10-12-06.png`

The problem here is that the blob starts with "/BAs1nRTx".

Is it possible to access this object from a browser? I have tried

1. Removing the second slash so the url is: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events/BAs1nRTx/00001f240_2020-05-12_10-12-06.png`
2. Replacing the slash with %2F so the url is: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events/%2FBAs1nRTx/00001f240_2020-05-12_10-12-06.png`
3. Adding another slash so the url is: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events///BAs1nRTx/00001f240_2020-05-12_10-12-06.png`

None of these worked for me.

Is it possible to access this blob from a browser?

EDIT:

Here is what the portal shows [image]

Comment: How do you know it starts with `/`? What does it look like in the portal?

Comment: Is your blob publicly accessible? Or are you looking to see this blob in Azure Portal/Storage Explorer?

Comment: I just tried it and I am able to access a blob using same naming pattern without any problem. I simply used the blob URL and did not make any changes to it.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I altered the URL for privacy sake, so I'm not sure what you accessed

Comment: I've edited the question to include actual links of the one that doesn't work.

Here is one that does work that's in the same container: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events/i280Cu0Ju/0005925e8_2020-01-02_14-40-18.png`

Comment: I basically uploaded a blob in my storage account and was able to access it. My blob's URL was something like `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer//test/test.txt`. I simply pasted this in my browser's address bar and was able to access the blob.

Comment: BTW, when I accessed the following link: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events//i280Cu0Ju/0005925e8_2020-01-02_14-40-18.png`, I was able to download the blob without any problem.

Comment: However when I used the following link: `https://surveillanceprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/rpi-events//BAs1nRTx/00001f240_2020-05-12_10-12-06.png` I got an error. Please make sure that you have a virtual folder having `BAs1nRTx` name.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS That's the issue I have, my blob's name begins with "/BAs1nRTx", so does that mean it is inaccessible from a URL?

Comment: The file definitely exists in that URL. It just seems to not work because (I presume) it begins with a '/'

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. You should be able to access the blob. The link you shared in comments is different than the one you shared in the question.

Comment: @HongOoi I've added a screenshot to the question

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Yeah, I originally posted a fake url because of privacy, but I've changed them all to be legitimate now

Comment: This is totally weird and intriguing :). I can see the blob in listing but not able to download in the browser. In Fiddler, if I specify the x-ms-version request header to 2019-07-07, then I am able to download however if I omit this, then I am getting 404 error.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Does this mean it is possibly an Azure bug that was introduced after 2019-07-07?

Comment: I honestly don't know at this time. I'll need to do some more research. Can you tell me how the blobs were uploaded in the first place? My guess is that you're getting problems with just the newly uploaded blobs (the ones with the date in May).

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS They are uploaded from a python script. this blob is the first one that contains a '/' at the start, and it's only existed for a few weeks, so I'm not sure if older ones would have worked

Comment: I've checked the source and it looks like the Python client doesn't properly url encode blob container name.  forward slash gets treated strangely, related issues: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/1512  https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/2967 https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/440 https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/2989 and it doesn't seem like there is a way around it, as it treats forward slash as a directory with no name

Answer (score 2):

I have a file at /a/b/c/10dec.csv location same as yours.

[image: Uploaded File Location]

When I tried to download `https://[STORAGE_ACCOUNT].blob.core.windows.net/test-archive-container//a/b/c/10dec.csv` it failed.

But, when I tried to download using `https://[STORAGE_ACCOUNT].blob.core.windows.net/test-archive-container//a/b/c/10dec.csv?[BLOB SAS TOKEN]` it works.

So, I think directly using BLOB URL you cannot download from the Browser, you always need to authenticate. That's why you will need to provide SAS TOKEN.

Please **Generate SAS** as shown below:

[image: Generate SAS Token]

And use that URL in Browser, it will work.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: But then why am I able to download other blobs from the same Container without the use of the SAS token (provided they don't start with a "/")?

Comment: Have you tried with SAS token once? Just to make sure url with // works or not.

Comment: I shouldn't need to generate a SAS token though, this is for a public container. I can't generate the token for every blob I want to access (there are millions of them)

Comment: Yeah right. I suggest you create a support ticket on Azure. Maybe they will be able to help you out.

Comment: @A_toaster Please let me know if you get the answer from Azure Support. I would like to know how to access such blobs.